# Sonar login via LDAP fails after period of non-usage

Tags: authentication, ldap, sonarqube

Whenever there is no login to sonar for a period of time (e.g. first login on a day) the login loads for about 15 minutes before it fails:

`2014.01.23 10:06:17 DEBUG o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory  Initializing LDAP context {java.naming.provider.url=ldap://XXX:3890, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, java.naming.security.principal=XXX
ey=00000-XXX,ou=People,o=00000,dc=XXX,dc=net, java.naming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.referral=follow}
2014.01.23 10:14:11 DEBUG o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider  XXX:3890; socket closed
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: XXX:3890; socket closed
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.readReply(Connection.java:416) ~[na:1.6.0_13]`

If you parallelly try to login again it works instantaneously.

We assume the LDAP connection is terminated after a certain period of time and the LDAP connection pool doesn't detect it so the next try using this connection fails and the terminated connection is removed from the connection pool.

Is there any possibility to deactivate the connection pooling for debugging purpose? Didn't found any config parameters for this, but found logging snippets with "connection pooling disabled".

Sonar version: 3.5.1
LDAP plugin version. 1.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this problem by setting two system properties in the wrapper.conf:

```
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize=0
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=3600000
```